# libtorrent dht peer request?

Tags: python, uri, bittorrent, pex, dht

Ive been playing around with the python bindings for libtorrent/rasterbar.
What I wanted to do was generate a new 'node-id' and reannounce it to the other nodes.

I read that a 'bencoded dicionary' needs to be created and I assume announced using something like force_dht_reannounce, is this correct?

Answer (score 4):

You can force libtorrent to use a specific node ID for the DHT by crafting a session-state file, and feed it to the `session::load_state()` function. Once you do this, you also need to restart the DHT by calling `session::stop_dht()` followed by `session::start_dht()`.

The relevant parts of the session state you need to craft have the following format (bencoded):

```
  {
    "dht state": {
      "node-id": "<20-byte binary node-ID>"
    }
  }
```

If you want to keep the rest of the session state, it might be a good idea to first call `session::save_state()` and then simply insert/overwrite the `node-id` field.

Something like this:

```
state = ses.save_state()
state["dht state"]["node-id"] = "<...>";
ses.load_state(state)
ses.stop_dht()
ses.start_dht()
```